# How to fill up form using CasperJS without form tag

Tags: javascript, casperjs, html-input

I'm new to CasperJS and I'm having problems in logging in into this site http://weibo.com/login.php

here's what I've tried

```
this.fill('form#contact-form', {
    'username':    'test@test.com',
    'password':    'anypassword',

}, true);
```

I can't used that since it has no form.

so I tried a different method using sendKeys.

```
this.sendKeys('.W_input ', 'tinkerbell@gmail.com');
```

Now my problem in here is that the input text has no ID in it, only a CLASS and both username and password have the same CLASS in it. how can i type into that textbox using only that class? or is it possible to use sendKeys using XPath?

Comment: `sendKeys` use keyboard event to input. That may cause some weird problem...

Answer (score 8):

casper supports CSS3 selectors ([tuts+ has a decent rundown of the top 30 you should memorize](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)) so you could do something like:

`this.sendKeys('input[name=username]', 'tinkerbell@gmail.com');`

Answer (score 5):

I use querySelector function to set username and password with success:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
casper.start('http://www.weibo.com', function() {
    this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
        document.querySelector('input[node-type="username"]').value = username;
        document.querySelector('input[node-type="password"]').value = password;
        document.querySelector('.W_btn_g:eq(1)').click();
    }, 'your_username', 'your_password');

});

casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(50000, function() {
        this.echo("50s");
    });

});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('weibo.png');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Explanation would be nice!

Answer (score -1):

This is simple casper js script to fill login form 
assuming it has mentioned id's for each field

casper.evaluate(function(username, password) {
          document.querySelector('input#user_email').value = username;

```
      document.querySelector('input#user_password').value = password;
      document.querySelector('input#login-button').click();
  }, 'email@email.com', 'password');
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how this solves the problem. Code-only answers are discouraged, as they don't teach anything. Also please indent the first line of code by 4 spaces so it is formatted properly. Thank you!